# How to use sendgrid to send email using ReactJS and firebase?

Tags: reactjs, sendgrid

I have made contactform component and I am using sendgrid and firebase. I have installed sendgrid and firebase and I am pushing data into firebase that data must be displayed inside email in sendgrid.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_SENDER_ID
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    //Reference content from collection 
    let contentref = firebase.database().ref('content');

  //SendGrid Email
  //const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY);

class ContactForm extends Component {

render() {

    return <div> (
 const msg = {
    to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    from: 'test@example.com',
    subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
  };
  sgMail.send(msg);

 </div>);
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

I am not getting email on `myemail@gmail.com` why so ?

Comment: React Components should return valid html or null.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings How can I integrate sendgrid with reactjs and firebase

Answer (score 0):

You must follow Sendgrid recommendation and use a [server-based application](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/).

`Making your API key publicly accessible could result in anyone authenticating API calls with your API key — this is a significant security concern both for you and SendGrid.`

- Create an Express server which consumes your built application, adding a route for an [email sender service](https://gist.github.com/wgrisa/5c7f5e20d845fc1fa0c181279cd3927f).

```js
app.post('/email', (req, res) => sendEmail(req.body, res))
```

- In your React application, you can use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to call your route.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const sendEmail = async (data) => axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/email',
  data
})
```

- Build a Sendgrid email message following their documentation and your needs, e.g.:

```
  {
    personalizations: [
      {
        to: [
          {
            email: 'some@email.com',
            name: 'Someone',
          },
        ],
        subject: 'test',
      },
    ],
    from: {
      email: 'who@sent.com',
      name: 'who sent',
    },
    reply_to: {
      email: 'email@to.com',
      name: 'reply',
    },
    content: [
      {
        type: 'text/html',
        value: 'HELLO WORLD',
      },
    ],
  }
```

- Call your axios function from before in your component:

```
const sendRequestDemoEmail = async (emailMessage) => {
  return await sendEmail(emailMessage)
}
```